# Emacs's <C-l> vim equivalent

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts

There's a neat <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd> hotkey in Emacs that repetitively moves the cursor to the top/middle/bottom of the screen. I'm quite sure there's a vim equivalent for that, but I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 8):

As an alternative, you can use the vim commands that refer to `scrolling relative to cursor`. Some of them have the advantage of leaving the cursor at the same column of the originating line.  From the `vim` help (`:help zz`):

> z  Redraw, line [count] at top of window (default cursor line). 
>   Put cursor at first non-blank in the line.
>
> zt  Like "z", but leave the cursor in the same column.  {not in
>   Vi}
>
> z{height}  Redraw, make window {height} lines tall.  This is
>   useful to make the number of lines small when screen  updating is very
>   slow.  Cannot make the height more than the physical screen height.
>
> z.  Redraw, line [count] at center of window (default cursor line). 
>   Put cursor at first non-blank in the line.
>
> zz  Like "z.", but leave the cursor in the same column. Careful: If
>   caps-lock is on, this command becomes "ZZ": write buffer and exit! 
>   {not in Vi}
>
> z-  Redraw, line [count] at bottom of window (default cursor line). 
>   Put cursor at first non-blank in the line.
>
> zb  Like "z-", but leave the cursor in the same column. {not in Vi}

Comment: To make this answer more concise, type zt to redraw with the cursor top, zb to redraw with the cursor bottom, zz to redraw with the cursor middle. The <C-l> command in Emacs cycles though zz, zt, zb.

Answer (score 3):

There is an equivalent - for both `vi` and `vim` :

`H` for top

`M` for middle and

`L`
 for the bottom of the screen

Comment: That's not equivalent. `vim`'s `H`, `M`, and `L` keep the same text on the screen, just moving the cursor to the appropriate line in the file. The `emacs` `Control-L` keeps the cursor on the same line in the file, shifting the portion of the file that you're seeing (like `vim`'s various `z` commands mentioned in [Luis's answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/108624/10454).

Comment: You are right. These are alternative to Meta-r in Emacs.

Comment: Thank you for the correction, still useful information though that can be combined with the right answer!

Answer (score 3):

Luis's answer above is correct, but the description in vim's help is a little bit unclear without a bit of experimentation. I am posting here the results of that experimentation.

To move the line that the current cursor is on to the top of screen, we need `z-<CR>`, which is typing `z` followed by `[Enter]` on the keyboard.

To move the line that the current cursor is on to the middle of the screen, we use `zz`.

To get the last behavior of `C-L`, we use `z-`.